# c# modify a generic property

Tags: c#, generics, properties

I have a viewmodel with 2 properties of the same type (bool). I like to have a function which sets one of the properties to a bool value.
Let's say you have a IsReadonly property.

```
public void SetReadOnly(MyViewModel vm, bool newVal)
{
    vm.IsReadOnly = newVal;
}
```

Now i want to make it more generic, and have a function for both:

```
public void SetBooleanProperty(MyViewModel vm, bool newVal, ?bool? myProperty)
{
    vm.myProperty = newVal; // sure this is an error, myProperty doesn't exist in the viewmodel. But that shows the way i like to have. 
}
```

I started this approach:

```
public void SetBooleanproperty<TProp>(MyViewModel vm, bool newVal, TProp myProperty)
{
     vm.??? = newVal;
}
```

I don't like to use a function GetPropertyByName("IsReadonly") which i think is available somewhere in the reflection classes from .Net. 
Reason: If another developer refactors the project and renames IsReadonly, the string wouldn't get updated. Is there a solutiuon for this ?

Comment: Where do you decide which property you want to set value?

Comment: when the user check / unchecks a checkbutton, the deoendency property's callback changes the viewmodel property. For several reasons, I traverse a viewmodel tree, and like to have ONE function for both booleans's. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use reflection without using reflection. I don't think you're going to find an answer. There are no generics against properties in the language.

Closest thing I can think of, which is awful, would be to pass in an action - this is pretty ridiculous, but it works. Please don't do this:

```
public void PerformAction(MyViewModel vm, bool newVal,
    Action<MyViewModel, bool> action)
{
    action(vm, newVal);
}

PerformAction(someViewModel, true, (vm, b) => vm.IsReadOnly = b);
```

Comment: from the maintenance view and clarity, looks plausible to me. Why you wouldn't recommend it ?

Comment: Because instead of writing normal code like `someViewModel.IsReadOnly = true`, you're writing `PerformAction(someViewModel, true, (vm, b) => vm.IsReadOnly = b);`. It requires that your property is exposed, so there's zero security benefit, and it's confusing to read and unnecessarily verbose. Just because something looks cool doesn't mean it's a good idea. Regular code that people can understand is almost always preferred to fancy code that people have to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a good way to do that. You don't want to combine getters and setters. Standard practice is to have a getter and setter for each value so you can control access to them. Having a getter and setter for both variables defeats the general purpose of having getters and setters.

Comment: I mean, at that point you might as well just make both values public and change them directly.

Comment: Right. The short function is just for demonstration. I like to set the property on a viewmodel tree. So the function has some more liones and is not just a setter. My challenge is that the "traversing code", which sets the boolean to each viewmodel, should be just in ONE function.